# Where Can I Download the Emacs v18 Source Code?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to find a version of Emacs that will compile on OpenBSD running on a DEC VAX. Versions 21 and 23 even Zile from the Ports tree fail to compile. I am hoping version 18 would; but where can I download it? The GNU FTP server only goes as far back as version 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the older stuff has been moved into the `old-gnu` top-level directory.  You can find it here: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/emacs-18.59.tar.gz